# Fasting as a reason for downfall of the hundred Kauravas (sons of Gandhari)

Tags: mahabharata, fasting, kauravas

Consider the following verse regarding prohibited vrat

> Gandhari fasted on a day when the **tenth and eleventh phases** of the
> moon were mixed. Her hundred sons perished. Hence such days shall be
> avoided for fasting purposes.
>
> [[2, Chapter 125: Sacred Rites (Vratas),  Garuda Purana]](https://archive.org/details/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/page/n381/mode/2up)

Tenth phase of the moon is Dasami and eleventh phase is Ekadasi. Fasting on the day with both Dasami and Ekadasi is prohibited according to this verse.

Do any other scripture mention this as a reason for perishing of Kauravas?